# Procedure too large excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Any idea how to put this code smaller?
This code how it is don't run on VBA 
How to aplly sub procedures here?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)




For J = 17 To 19
Select Case Target.Address
  Case "$J$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J17:J19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$J$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J18:J18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$J$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J19:J19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select
Next
```

another FOR

```
 For N = 17 To 19
 Select Case Target.Address
  Case "$N$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N17:N19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$N$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N18:N18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$N$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N19:N19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select
Next
```

another FOR

```
For R = 17 To 19
Select Case Target.Address

  Case "$R$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R17:R19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$R$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R18:R18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$R$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R19:R19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select
Next
```

another FOR

```
For V = 17 To 19
Select Case Target.Address

  Case "$V$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V17:V19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$V$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V18:V18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$V$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V19:V19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select
Next
```

other
    For Z = 17 To 19
    Select Case Target.Address

```
  Case "$Z$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z17:Z19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$Z$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z18:Z18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$Z$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z19:Z19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select
Next
```

And so on

```
 For AH = 16 To 16
 Select Case Target.Address
  Case "$AH$16"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AH16:AJ16")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(2, 0) = Date
    End If
 End Select
Next





End Sub
```

There are ± 160 For

Comment: This is VBA telling you to think differently.

Comment: Your loops seem to serve no purpose?

Comment: Loops only for check 3 lines each time. The lines that ar ont included have text info. However, I will try (later) to change this layout to reduce loops.

Comment: _Whenever_ you see copy and paste coding, it is time to move things into a function that is called multiple times via loops.

Comment: This is the famous `for-switch` paradigm (http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Switched_on_Loops)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use it!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the code is not yet optimized and might include some redundancies you might want to eliminate first. This is especially due to the fact that all this code is residing on the `Worksheet_Change` event. So each time you change **any** cell on that sheet the entire code will fire and take a long time to run.

Still if you wish to proceed then you can just encapsulate all these `FOR` into smaller `Sub`s and call them one after the other from the main `Sub`. Here is short sample to demonstrate the idea:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

For J = 17 To 19
Select Case Target.Address
  Case "$J$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J17:J19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$J$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J18:J18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$J$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J19:J19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select

Call MoreChecks1(Target)
Call MoreChecks2(Target)
Call MoreChecks3(Target)

Next


Public Sub MoreChecks1(ByVal Target As Range)

 For N = 17 To 19
 Select Case Target.Address
  Case "$N$17"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N17:N19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$N$18"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N18:N18")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If

  Case "$N$19"
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N19:N19")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
  End If
End Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel is giving an error Sub or Function not defined. Any idea?

Comment: The above code is not complete. I don't have all of your `FOR`s. There is currently only a sample `Sub` called `MoreChecks1` which includes the first bulk of your `FOR`. You will have to add the other `Sub`s `MoreChecks2`, `MoreChecks3`, etc. to include the other `FOR`s you mentioned.

Comment: You're right. 
That works. 
So, this will work with several call's? Around 160? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it should. The only other limitation I am aware of is the 64KB limit for each VBA module. Apparently, no module should exceed more than 64KB. Otherwise you will get another error. In that case you can just move all additional `Sub`s to new modules and you should be fine again. Here is more on that subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240819(VS.60).aspx

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will build the code and will see.
Thanks for your help! (I'm not able to put a positive feedback)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your volume of code significantly using a little more logic:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range, tg As Range

    Set c = Target.Cells(1) 'in case of multiple cells updated...

    Set tg = Me.Range("J17:J19") 'first range to check for updates

    Do While tg(1).Column <= 26 'Col Z
        If Not Application.Intersect(c, tg) Is Nothing Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = Date
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set tg = tg.Offset(0, 4) 'move tg over 4 cols to the right
    Loop

End Sub
```

You should also be aware that `Target` can contain multiple cells (such as when a user pastes content into the sheet, or selects multiple cells, enters a value, then presses Ctrl+Enter), so you may need to account for that.

In my example above I'm just using the first cell.

A slightly different approach:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range, tg As Range, rw As Long

    Set c = Target.Cells(1) 'in case of multiple cells updated...

    Set tg = Me.Range("J:J,N:N,R:R,V:V,Z:Z") 'columns to check for updates

    If Not Application.Intersect(c, tg) Is Nothing Then
        rw = c.Row
        'check valid row: add more checks as required
        If (rw >= 17 And rw <= 19) Or _
           (rw >= 307 And rw <= 309) Then

            On Error Goto haveError
            Application.EnableEvents = False 
            c.Offset(0, 1) = Date
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If 'tracked row
    End If     'tracked column

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    'always make sure this is turned back on...
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I have 5 columns [J;N;R;V;Z] (days) with 30 lines each x 5 weeks.The purpose is to register the cell modification inserting the date after it. 

Please check line example here http://i.imgur.com/2BlMKgo.png

With yout method I need to do it range by range right? A loop by column it can't be done because there are empty cells between the column (290 lines)..

Comment: I added another example: you should be able to modify one of those to work for your data...

Comment: Yep, it works! Much easier than last example. I noted some (micro)seconds long to insert data. Is normal, right? Thanks Tim!

Comment: Slight edit above - you do not want to capture an event when you update the date cell, so you can turn off event handling for that step.  Also added some error handling to make sure events get turned back on in the event something errors out.